# Finding happy numbers

Tags: java, programming-challenge

This is a [practice question](https://leetcode.com/problems/happy-number/):

> A happy number is a number defined by the following process:
>
> Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of
>   the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number
>   equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which
>   does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are
>   happy numbers.

Example: 19 is a happy number

\$1^2 + 9^2 = 82\$

\$8^2 + 2^2 = 68\$

\$6^2 + 8^2 = 100\$

\$1^2 + 0^2 + 0^2 = 1\$

Program below solves this problem:

```
public static boolean isHappy(int n) {
   int sum=0;
   Set<Integer> seenSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    while (n > 0) {
        int x = n%10;
        sum+=x*x;
        n=n/10;

        if (n == 0 && sum != 1) {
            n=sum;
            sum=0;
            seenSet.add(n);
        } else if (n== 0 && sum == 1 ) {
            return true;
        }
            else if (seenSet.contains(n)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm looking for any comments on how to improve the code, but a specific focus on whether the way the method returns from multiple places would be appreciated - the multiple return statements concern me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The repeated `n == 0` conditions are not pretty. It would be better to turn that part into a nested condition to avoid the duplication. It will also help simplifying the two conditions on `sum`.

In addition, there is one more comparison with 0 of `n`: in the loop condition. That's unnecessary, because `n` will never become 0. Only if the input is 0, but then the current implementation will return true, which is wrong, since 0 is not a happy number. As such, the loop can be `while (true)` infinite loop, and your could replace the last return statement with `throw new IllegalStateException("whaaaat? How did you get here? ")` or similar.

The overall logic would be easier to follow if you separate the summing of the digits from the method exit control. You could add a helper function that returns the sum of the squares of digits. Based on that result you could decide to return a value or continue for another round.

You can replace `n=n/10` with `n /= 10`.

The formatting is messy too. Try the auto reformat feature of your favorite IDE.

Comment: changing n = n/10 to n/=10 improves the run time from 224ms to 208ms.

Comment: @linoox I would expect `n = n / 10` and `n /= 10` to compile to exactly the same code. You can verify that using `javap -c`.

Comment: i found that surprising too. I ran it again and this time it took the same as original (224ms). I should have run it multiple times before commenting here and misleading others. It was strange that's why earlier i tried to make similar changes to sum+=x*x by eliminating x and directly substituting but it took longer. The OJ might not be accurate or could be running on VMs with differing configurations.

Comment: @200_success, what about the running time of this solution? just curious.

Comment: runtime on leetcode OJ was 224ms for the posted solution